# Заказ билетов с использованием jquery ui autocomplete

Tags: php, jquery, json, jquery-ui

Есть такая формочка заказ билетов, где нужно указать *откуда* летишь и *куда*:

```js
$('.js-autocomplete').on('focus', function(){
        window.autocomplite_items = false
        $(this).autocomplete({ 
            source:'https://ufsa.com.ua/ufsa/autocomplete.php', 
            minLength: 2, 
            autoFocus : true,
            select: function( event, ui ) {
                console.log('select');
                window.autocomplite_items = true
                $(this).next().val(ui.item.id);
            },
            close: function(event, ui) {
                if(!window.autocomplite_items && this.value.length >= 2) {
                    var alias = this
                    $.get('https://ufsa.com.ua/ufsa/autocomplete.php?b&term=' + this.value , {} , function(tpl) {
                        try {
                            var obj = eval('(' + tpl + ')');
                            $(alias).next().val(obj[0].id)
                        } catch(e) {
                            console.debug(e)
                        }
                    })
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

  <br>
  <br>
  
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="from" id="from" class="form-control js-autocomplete" placeholder="Откуда">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="to" id="to" class="form-control js-autocomplete" placeholder="Куда">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Использую [jquery ui autocomplete](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) и [json файл с др. сайта](https://ufsa.com.ua/ufsa/autocomplete.php).

Задача, при фокусе на поле должны высвечиваться варианты аэропортов - город + код аэропорта ([например как тут](https://hrk.aero/kupit-bilet/) - *не реклама, исключительно как пример).

**Вопрос:** Как реализовать автокомплит городов с аэропортами, возможно, есть международными и общедоступный jsonp файл с подобными данными? Что для php нужно?

И как реализовать несовпадение откуда и куда (при вводе города *откуда*, чтобы в *куда* уже он не высвечивался)?

**P.S:** И если в дальнейшем планируется интеграция в Wordpress, возможно, есть готовые плагины\виджеты для реализации подобного?

Answer (score 5):

> возможно, есть международными и общедоступный jsonp файл с подобными
>   данными?

Есть сервисы, которые предоставляют API поиска по аэропортам (например, https://developer.flightstats.com/api-docs/airports/v1), но по очевидным причинам, они платные и при определённой нагрузке это может стать не выгодно.

Беглый поиск по GitHub выдаёт два репозитория с аэропортами, самый популярный обновлялся в 2015 году, другой — совсем недавно, хоть и создан в 2014, что добавляет трастовости:
https://github.com/mwgg/Airports

Данные можно получать скриптом (самое простое — `git pull`-ить репозиторий), а затем конвертировать результаты в какую-либо бд для более быстрого поиска.

> Задача, при фокусе на поле должны высвечиваться варианты аэропортов -
>   город + код аэропорта (например как тут - *не реклама, исключительно
>   как пример).

В вашем примере данные начинают возвращаться только при вводе двух символов, просто выпадайка с аэропортами будет изначально добавляться к весу страницы (например, json в репозитории, который я привёл выше, весит 8.9 мегабайт)

> Что для php нужно?

PHP пригодится для того, чтобы не возвращать во фронтенд список всех аэропортов, а получать только те, которые удовлетворяют поисковому запросу.

Сама реализация сильно зависит от нагрузки и инструментов (например, фреймворка), которые вы выберете.
В целом, это же справедливо для инструментов на фронтенде, т. к., например, jquery ui тянет за собой много зависимостей (js, css), которые могут оказаться лишними.

> И как реализовать несовпадение откуда и куда (при вводе города откуда,
>   чтобы в куда уже он не высвечивался)?

Для этого достаточно при отправке запроса из второго `select` на бекенд передавать код уже найденного в первом селекте аэропорта.
При определённом допущении, код для получения списка аэропортов может быть одинаковым и в него будут передаваться текущие значения обоих `select`.

Я постарался ответить на ваши вопросы, но в целом, вопросы довольно комплексные и ответ может перейти в дискуссию о поставщике данных, сохранении результатов, кешировании выборе компонентов и технологий для фронтенда и бэкенда.

Если потребуются какие-то уточнения — пишите, я обновлю ответ.

Comment: Я приношу извинения, конкурс заканчивается, но я не могу Ваш ответ отметить решением, как и отдать за него баллы, потому как не вижу конкретики! Только общая идея. Что-то нашла более существенное https://gabrieleromanato.name/adding-jquery-ui-autocomplete-to-the-wordpress-search-form , правда, автокомплит по поиску и еще не было времени проверить, но  хотя бы есть наглядный код с php.
В любом случае, огромное спасибо за старания! Плюсик уже поставила!)

Comment: С конкретикой на WP всё равно бы не помог, а писать что-то абстрактное, не привязанное к WP — вам бы не пригодилось. В любом случае, интересно было копнуть тему с кодами аэропортов, так что всё ок :)